# reactjs resetting props for componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: reactjs

First question from my first react project.

I'm trying to figure out how to best effect a component on a specific onClick link, to be able to retrigger this effect and to not have it effected by other links on the page. The first two asks are working, but I can't seem to have other links not effect the component.

I have a DisplayLightbox component on my page accepting a couple values

```
<div>
  <DisplayLightbox 
    showLightbox = {this.state.showLightbox} 
    lightboxValue = {this.state.travelCity}  
  /> 
</div>
```

The link I want to trigger the lightbox is calling a function that sets the state (and sends the prop). This part seems to work fine.

```
onClick={() => this.showLightbox(el.field_city)}

showLightbox(travelCity){
  this.setState({
    showLightbox: true,
    travelCity: travelCity,
  });
}
```

In my DisplayLightbox component, the componentWillReceiveProps does set state to true, which adds the lb-active class in the div, which, from the css, displays the lightbox div. This seems fine.

```
class DisplayLightbox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    showLightbox: false, 
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.showLightbox !== this.state.showLightbox) {
      this.setState({ showLightbox: nextProps.showLightbox });
    }
  } 

  closeLightbox() {
    this.setState({
      showLightbox: false,
    });
  }

  render() {
    var lbActive = (this.state.showLightbox === true) ? "lb-active" : "" 
    return <div className={"lightbox " + lbActive }>
    <div className={"lightbox-close " + lbActive }  onClick={() => 
  this.closeLightbox()}>CLOSE</div>
    Copy in lightbox
    </div>;
  }
}
```

Looking into it, I see that since props are not controlled by the component and read-only, once it's set as True and I close the div by setting the state of showLighbox back to false, the nextProps.showLightbox remains true. So, if I close it (closeLightbox) and click a different onClick on my page, it still looks into my component, sees nextProps.showLightbox is still set to TRUE and opens the lightbox.

I only want the lightbox open if that specific link is the one being clicked though. It would seem overkill to have every other link setting the state of showLightbox to false, so I'm guessing I'm not looking at this properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could just move your `closeLightbox` method to upper component and manage `showLightbox` prop from parent. Then component `DisplayLightbox` will have 3 props: `showLightbox`, `travelCity` and method `closeLightbox`.

When you move closing lightbox to parent component, event `componentWillReceiveProps` should be no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks SO MUCH for this speedy reply. I've added a button div to the parent which toggles the showLightbox state and I was, as you said, able to remove the componentWillReceiveProps from the child. Seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

> It would seem overkill to have every other link setting the state of
>   showLightbox to false, so I'm guessing I'm not looking at this
>   properly.

Why not configure only the one link you want to turn on / off the lightbox then?

As i see it, a component who gets its active state from the parent or external component, should not bother to manage it in its own state.
You can manage the on / off state in the parent's state and pass down a `isOn` and `onClose` event handler to the `LightBox`.
Once the `LightBox` was clicked it will invoke the handler passed down to it and the parent will change the state of `isOn` to `false`, this will trigger a render with a new prop of `isOn` for the `LightBox` this time it's value is `false`.
While clicking the external `link` / `button` the parent will listen to it and change the state of `isOn` to `true`, and again `isOn` will passed down to `LightBox` with it's shiny new value of `true`.

Small example:

```js
const cities = ["ny", "tlv", "ark"];

class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }

  onClick() {
    const { item, onClick } = this.props;
    onClick(item);
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.onClick}>{this.props.children}</button>;
  }
}

class LightBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }

  onClick() {
    const { city, onClick } = this.props;
    onClick(city);
  }

  render() {
    const { isOn } = this.props;
    const css = `lightBoxStyle ${isOn && "onStyle"}`;
    return (
      <div 
        className={css}
        onClick={this.onClick}>
        |
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      turnedOn: []
    };

    this.on = this.on.bind(this);
    this.off = this.off.bind(this);
  }

  on(city) {
    const { turnedOn } = this.state;
    if (turnedOn.find(c => c === city)) {
      return;
    }
    const nextState = [...turnedOn, city];
    this.setState({ turnedOn: nextState });
  }

  off(city) {
    const nextState = this.state.turnedOn.filter(c => c !== city);
    this.setState({ turnedOn: nextState });
  }

  render() {
    const { turnedOn } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {cities.map((city, i) => {
          const isOn = turnedOn && turnedOn.includes(city);

          return (
            <div style={{ display: "inline-block", margin: "0 10px" }}>
              <LightBox city={city} isOn={isOn} onClick={this.on} />
              <hr />
              <Button item={city} onClick={this.off}>
                Close the light!
              </Button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.lightBoxStyle{
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 1px #222;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.onStyle{
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This is fantastic! I used your button idea, although as a hidden div that only displays when showLightbox is true. 
Also, "a component who gets its active state from the parent or external component, should not bother to manage it in its own state" is hugely helpful. Although, within class DisplayLightbox, that would be where I add the functionality to what live within (I believe).

Comment: indeed, you can manage a state within `LightBox` but it should be a state that only concern `LightBox`. Remember, In the _Matrix_ movie, "Neo" didn't decide to be the chosen one, an external force decided it for him  :)

Comment: @user1932694 by the way if you think it was helpful you can upvote the answer and if the answer provided a solution for you then you should accept it in order to mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the great replies, I took the close out of the child and back to the parent. 
I did this by adding a lightbox-button div to the parent

```
        <div className={"lightbox-button " + this.state.showLightbox} onClick={() => this.showLightbox()}></div>

       <DisplayLightbox 
       showLightbox = {this.state.showLightbox} 
      lightboxValue = {this.state.travelCity}  />
```

This calls the same function showLightbox, that I modified slightly to toggle

```
  showLightbox(travelCity){
this.setState({
  showLightbox: !this.state.showLightbox,
  travelCity: travelCity,
});
```

}

Using css, I keep this lightbox-button hidden, unless this.state.showLightbox is true. When that happens, the button displays and, when click, toggles the showLightbox state, thereby removing the lightbox and button.

Not sure if this is the ideal solution, but it seems to be working.